# I can't seem to get the app.json right for being able to Deploy app with Google Admin API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy (java) based application to google's app-engine through the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-overview.

I seem to fail to get the app.json right so that all the files(resources) from my application will be actually deployed to the App Engine.

The guide here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/creating-config-files tells something like:

*to manually define all of the resources that are located in your Cloud Storage bucket, you **use the reference information** in the deployment section of the apps.services.versions collection.*

I can't figure out how to use this reference. 
Did someone bump into this and got it solved?

**Note:** If I use the *mvn appengine:deploy* command locally (in the app folder) the resource files are automatically **staged** to the Cloud Storage bucket and **deployed** to the App Engine. I want to achieve the **similar behavior through Admin API calls**.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei, Im not able to clearly understand if its the configuration of the required *app.json* file that is causing your deployment to fail, or if its the order of steps taken. Let me try covering the process and necessary steps to see if it helps.

When you use the Admin API to deploy your app to App Engine, the actual files that get deployed to App Engine, are the files that you have uploaded to your Cloud Storage bucket (not the copy of your app on your local machine). So, unlike the Maven commands, you must first upload your app (all the files that you want to deploy to App Engine) into your Cloud Storage bucket before you can deploy those files to App Engine.

- The manual steps for running the gsutil commands are in the *Uploading App Resources* topic.
- To upload your app programmatically, you can use the methods of the [Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics) (see the *REST APIS* tab under *Uploading an object*).

After you have your app uploaded to your Cloud Storage bucket, you are then able to map the bucket location of those files in your *app.json* file.

The *app.json* file is ultimately a converted-.json-version of your *appengine-web.xml* file with the additional "deployments section" (which defines the Cloud Storage bucket mapping of all the files you want to deploy to App Engine).

- To convert the contents of your *appengine-web.xml* file into the .json format, you can use the *apps.services.versions collection* reference.
- To define the "deployments section", refer to the *Creating JSON Configuration Files* topic.

With your app's files uploaded to your Cloud Storage bucket and an *app.json* that points to those files, you should be ready to send the POST request and deploy your app to App Engine.